# Parâmetro da função eeprom_write_block

Tags: c++, funções, arduino

Olá! Estava realizando alguns testes utilizando a biblioteca `avr/eeprom.h` no meu Arduino. Uma das funções dela é a `eeprom_write_block(x, y, z)`, que escreve um bloco de memória no EEPROM. O primeiro parâmetro (`x`) é a variável que eu quero escrever, o segundo (`y`) é o byte do EEPROM aonde eu vou começar a escrever e o terceiro (`z`) é o número de bytes que eu vou escrever. Contudo, vi em alguns locais a seguinte variação: `eeprom_write_block(&x, y, z)`. Testei algumas vezes essa variação: em algumas funciona com ou sem o `&`, mas outras só funciona se tiver `&`. Alguém poderia esclarecer que diferença o `&` traz para a função e em que momentos usá-lo?

Grato

Answer (score 0):

A função `eeprom_write_block()` recebe três parâmetros: o endereço de memória de onde o dado será copiado, o endereço de memória para o onde o dado será copiado e o tamanho do dado a ser copiado. Como a origem do dado deve ser o **endereço de uma váriavel** (de qualquer tipo -- uma `struct`, `int`, *array* de `char`, etc) você deve passar o ponteiro para a variável a ser copiada.

Sabendo disso, você deve entender quando usar o operador `&` ou não. A linguagem C é bastante complexa e para você entender esse assunto completamente precisaríamos de muitas páginas, portanto vou passar uma regra simples que deve sanar a sua dúvida inicial e funcionar para a maioria dos casos, mas se você pretende continuar programando Arduino **recomendo fortemente ler um livro sobre a linguagem C**. Creio que a minha resposta irá criar novas dúvidas na sua cabeça e para saná-las você tem que entender melhor a linguagem, mas vamos lá.

Você deve usar o operador `&` quando precisar obter o ponteiro para uma variável e não deve usá-lo quando a própria variável é um ponteiro ou *array*. Exemplo:

```c
struct Xpto {
    // declaração qualquer
};

// Variáveis normais
char c;
int i;
float f;
double d;
Xpto xpto;

eeprom_write_block(&c, sizeof(c), x);
eeprom_write_block(&i, sizeof(i), x);
eeprom_write_block(&f, sizeof(f), x);
eeprom_write_block(&d, sizeof(d), x);
eeprom_write_block(&xpto, sizeof(xpto), x);

// Variáveis do tipo ponteiro
char *pc = &c; // ponteiro para char
int *pi = &i; // ponteiro para int
float *pf = &f; // ponteiro para float
double *pd = &d; // ponteiro para double
Xpto *pxpto = &xpto; // ponteiro para estrutura Xpto
char *foobarString = "foobar"; // string
int numerosPrimos[100]; // array de int
float coordenadas[3]; // array de float

eeprom_write_block(pc, sizeof(c), x);
eeprom_write_block(pi, sizeof(i), x);
eeprom_write_block(pf, sizeof(f), x);
eeprom_write_block(pd, sizeof(d), x);
eeprom_write_block(pxpto, sizeof(xpto), x);
eeprom_write_block(foobarString, strlen(foobarString), x);
eeprom_write_block(numerosPrimos, sizeof(numerosPrimos), x);
eeprom_write_block(coordenadas, sizeof(coordenadas), x);
```

PS: Não se deve ler valores de variáveis não inicializadas, portanto você deve inicializá-las antes de passá-las à função `eeprom_write_block()`.

PS2: As chamadas *strings*, são nada mais que ponteiros para `char` e devem ser passadas sem o operador `&`.